# Write my PHP code without dependency to mvc framework?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, frameworks, dependencies

Currently I'm learning SOLID and how high level code should not depend on low level code.

But what if I don't want my code (my controllers for ex.) to be dependent on let's say a laravel mvc framework.

If I implement a laravel view, which probably has an interface, I create my code to be dependent on that interface, an interface I don't own. So if I want to move my code to another framework with another view engine, I have a dependency to that interface and I have to change my code.

So would it be OK to create an adapter between my code and the framework?
That does mean I'm going to write an interface for each framework connection there is. I'm somewhat limiting the functions the framework has to offer. But my code is moveable to another system.

Any ideas on this? Somewhat confused by how this is done. What is the best way to upgrade for example from laravel 4 to 5, would it be creating adapters for everything you need from the framework?

Comment: then all you've done is move the dependency elsewhere. "Time to move the code, oh... dang, now I have to rewrite the adapter".

Comment: I assume I have to rewrite the adapter, but that would be a much easier job than changing the implementation in the code. Assuming that the next framework I go to has sort of the same features (like views, ORM,.. just to name a few).

Comment: You are trying to abstract the abstraction. That makes little sense in the end.

Comment: Ok, thanks for answering. So what it simply means is.. moving to another framework is going to change my code? Are there any other ideas to make this less painful?

Comment: SOLID is not meant to follow strictly. It is meant to use if possible.


It would be extremely hard to maintain this approach in the future. The more independent wheels you have in the system the harder it is to move them in one direction.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Solid says high level should not be dependend kn low level. Not he other way around. I was just wandering if this is condsidered good or bad practice. Now i know the answer ...